# WCF troubleshooting - async and zero results

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap, asynchronous

How do you troubleshoot a WCF Service consumption from the client side (silverlight)
when from the server you can tell that you service works (stepping through) and the client gets an ObservableCollection with nothing in it?

```
    void client_GetAddressesCompleted(object sender, GetAddressesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.Result;
        // ... more code
    }
```

e.Result always comes back with zero count. Even if it is working on the server. Any ideas?

**MORE INFO**
I think have tracked the problem back to the area where an intermediate layer calls a Java-based SOAP web service for the list of Address and then I passes the data down again via a WCF-based SOAP Service to a Silverlight client. The reference to the Java service is a "Service" reference. When doing this kind of interop does the fact the Java data transfer object does not have DataContracts and DataMembers matter? How does WCF handle this?

Comment: I'm sure you have problems with server method. So you should attach its code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start by turning on all the [diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).

Then Check the deserialization of you objects by implementing the [serializing functions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think its not a serialization problem because you should got an exception in this situation except you have some try catch, but may be some other event activates ur `client_GetAddressesCompleted` and so nothing will be passed to the arguments. check all events which will be raised in your application are routed truly.